# Is there a way to undo /remove / rollback EF 4.3 foreign key naming convention?

Tags: entity-framework-4, naming-conventions, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

Using EF code first, we have a db seeding framework that uses dependency injected Db initializers and seeders to populate a dev db with sample test data.

Some of these seeding operations need to import a lot of data, so for a couple of tables, we use actual SQL files with INSERT statements. For some of those insert statements, foreign keys must be diabled then re-enabled:

```
ALTER TABLE [Schema].[TableName] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [TableName_FkPropertyName]
-- perform a block of inserts
ALTER TABLE [Schema].[TableName] CHECK CONSTRAINT [TableName_FkPropertyName]
```

I just updated from EF 4.2 to EF 4.3 and noticed that these no longer work. An examination of the db created by EF shows that the FK's are now named differently:

```
FK_CodeFolder1.Table1Name_CodeFolder2.Table2Name_DbFkColumnName
```

Is there any way to remove this naming convention and go back to the original? If not, how is this not a [known issue or breaking change](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-released.aspx)?

**Update after Ladislav's Reply**

Ladislav is right, my above explanation of the new naming pattern was not quite right. I have updated it. The part preceding the . was not the full namespace, but it was the name of a folder in the entity model project. So if I had an entity WidgetAbc in folder AggregateSet1, the fk pattern fragment would be `AggregateSet1.WidgetAbc`, not just `WidgetAbc`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think it is an issue or breaking change? IMHO it is EF internal behavior - you are using code first and in this approach you were not supposed to work directly with database and especially you were not supposed to base your custom database scripts on hardcoded names because you don't have control over their generation.

I don't think you can revert the behavior but you can start using migrations and code your table definitions - [AddForeignKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829429%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method should allow you naming your FK constraint.

Btw. I see different naming pattern of FK constraints in EFv4.3:

```
FK_DependentTableName_PrincipalTableName_FKColumnName
```

Comment: I have to disagree about having control over name generation. The API gives you control over naming just about everything else that can materialize in SQL -- schema names, table names, column names, etc. If the new naming convention was at least published, that would be extremely helpful. We are lucky because for the most part we follow exactly what you said -- not creating a lot of custom SQL like views, indexes, sprocs, etc. I am looking forward to working with the new migration features as they mature, but still would like to understand why changing this naming pattern was necessary.

Comment: If you want to know why the pattern was changed you should ask directly ADO.NET team.

Comment: Is there any official info that FK naming changed? This was a breaking change when you apply migration, created in 4.3 or later version that deletes FK from db schema, when FK was created in pre 4.3 version!